# NSScrollview, Webview resizing problem when integrated with Java

Tags: java, macos, resize, webview, nsscrollview

I am developing an Desktop framework that is integrated with Java environment i.e the framework creates an NSView that is added to the Java view.

The view created in framework has scrollview as its subview. Both NSView and scrollview has autoresizing mask as NSViewWidthResizable and NSViewHeightResizable.

When I try resizing in Cocoa sample resizing of these views are working fine. But, when Java view is resized, the scrollview (document view) is not refreshed properly. The problem exists only if scrollview/webview (which has document view) as subview.

What is the reason for this? How do I solve this?